# How to know variable values in tikz for debugging

Tags: tikz-pgf, debugging

I am pretty fresh to tikz and I am trying to create a not-so-simple picture. I am also using the `calc` package with the let command, but the final figure is not the desired one. Therefore, I need to debug the code and I need to know the values computed within the let command.
In particular, given the command

```
\draw
let \p1 = ($(D1) - (D)$),
    \p2 = ($(D2) - (D)$),
    \n0 = {veclen(\x1, \y1)},
    %\n1 = {atan2(\x1, \y1)},
    %\n2 = {atan2(\x2, \y2)}
    \n1 = {atan(\x1/\y1) + 180*(\x1 < 0)},
    \n2 = {atan(\x2/\y2) + 180*(\x2 < 0)}
in (D1) arc(\n1:\n2:\n0);
```

is there a way to see the values `\n1` and `\n2`?
Note that I do not need to display them in the picture, but I need to know them just to check if these values are correct.
Thank you.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you clarified what you're trying to achieve, possibly also posting a short example with the code above. We don't know what `D1` or `D` are, except that they are coordinates/nodes.

Answer (score 4):

You can print their value into a node but if you just want to see them without doing any node trick then you can print them in the log file

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\def\shoutmyn#1{\expandafter\show\csname tikz@cc@n@#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node (D1) {D1};
\node (D) at (3,2) {D};
\node (D2) at (1,4) {D2};
\draw
let \p1 = ($(D1) - (D)$),
    \p2 = ($(D2) - (D)$),
    \n0 = {veclen(\x1, \y1)},
    %\n1 = {atan2(\x1, \y1)},
    %\n2 = {atan2(\x2, \y2)}
    \n1 = {atan(\x1/\y1) + 180*(\x1 < 0)},
    \n2 = {atan(\x2/\y2) + 180*(\x2 < 0)}
in \pgfextra{\shoutmyn{1}}(D1) arc(\n1:\n2:\n0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This for example prints on TexnicCenter

[image]

Comment: Gotta love `\shoutmyn`! `:)` I could actually write an `arara` rule that, besides compiling stuff, collects these contraptions from the log and prints them nicely in a tabular view... Oh no! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda How's the thesis going ? :P

Comment: it's... going... `:)`